# Best practice for defining machine specific resources in maven builds?

Tags: shell, maven, environment-variables

Is there a standard way to provision environment specific resources in a maven build?

For example - we expect that our build will run in environments where the specific IP address of a the local service which is used in an application is different.

One option is to set this as a shell environmental variable, but its not clear wether this will propogate down to the surefire jvm's which run unit tests.

Another option is to provision this information in the pom.xml subclassed file , but that comes with other baggage (each developer would need to maintain their own pom file), and this would of course break any sort of automated build environment.

Answer (score 1):

The following example shows how a build profile can be used to pick up different sets of property values.

## Example

You can use the **-P** parameter to activate one of the build profile

```
$ mvn -Ptest1 compile
..
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (default) @ demo ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
     [echo] arbitrary.property=1.0
..
```

Switching profile picks up the property value associated with the second profile:

```
$ mvn -Ptest2 compile
..
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (default) @ demo ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
     [echo] arbitrary.property=2.0
..
```

### pom.xml

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <echo message="arbitrary.property=${arbitrary.property}"/>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>test1</id>
            <properties>
                <arbitrary.property>1.0</arbitrary.property>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>test2</id>
            <properties>
                <arbitrary.property>2.0</arbitrary.property>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Surefire does its best to ensure that the forked JVM is as isolated as possible from variations in the users environment. If you want to pass thins through you need to use the [`systemPropertyVariables`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#systemPropertyVariables) configuration option to define the system properties for the forked JVM.

Others have mentioned profiles. In general using profiles to inject environment specific details is a bad plan, or even a Maven Anti-pattern. There is one and only one case were such profiles are not an anti-pattern (note I am not promoting to a pattern, only moving out of the anti-pattern category) that is where your profiles tweak the **test** environment *and* you are not attaching the `tests.jar` to the reactor. In such a case the "tweaked" artifacts will not escape their module to cause "bad things" (like uncertainty as to what profile was active when the artifact in the repository was deployed to the repo or whether the build is using the artifact from the local repo or a remote repo with a different profile)

I would use a system property on the CLI and pass it through to the integration tests using the `systemPropertyVariables` configuration option.

If you want something even more "maven way" you'd probably need a maven plugin to fire up the service that is to be tested against, but that can be very difficult for non java based services. See [cassandra-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/cassandra-maven-plugin) for an example of how to do that type of thing with a java based service.