# Loading properties from different locations

Tags: java, maven, properties, configuration

I am struggling for a solution to access configuration files from different places depending on different environments (`dev`, `prod`).

Here is an approximate layout of my project.

```
   │   pom.xml
   └───src
       └───main
           ├───java
           │       ConfigurationLoader.java
           ├───resources
           │       conf1.properties
           └───webapp
               │   web.xml
               └───WEB-INF
```

`ConfigurationLoader` is a self-described class and is supposed to be some plain singleton, statically available throughout the application.

In `dev` environment it should load `conf1.properties` from a classpath root, but in `prod` env it should find them in container's root folder (ex. `%TOMCAT_HOME%\bin`).

How to implement `ConfigurationLoader` properly for such kind of selective properties loading?

Thanks

***UPD:***

I am more interested in `ConfigurationLoader` implementation and property files locations. Problem is that how `ConfigurationLoader` locating those files. Something like:

```
String path = "/conf1.properties";
File confFile;
switch (environment) {
  case "dev": //classpath 
    URI location = ConfigurationLoader.class.getResource(path).toURI();
    confFile = new File(location);
  break;
  case "prod": //root (?)
    confFile = new File(path);
  break;
}
Properties p = new Properties(confFile);
```

Here comes several questions:

1. How should I pass environment variable to the code from Maven (defined in profiles or whatever)? I don't want to filter java classes, and probably preloading another property file with only environment entry. Also, I don't think I will be able to modify system properties (`-Denv=whatever`) on production platform.
2. What if properties file needs to contain paths for some resources to be accessed by other system components (ex. `applicationContext.xml` for spring which also should be on either classpath for `dev` or in that `bin` tomcat's folder)? How those paths should look like and how will I need them to be resolved in my code avoiding code duplication of that `ConfigurationLoader` section?

Is there a chance to resolve it more in maven and less in code, or what other approaches exist?

Comment: Can you not define 2 kind of environments and check with a if statement what evironment you are using at that moment? this might be in your settings file or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Love the question! We had the exact same problem, and solved it as follows. The structure of our project is basically the same, except for an extra `external-resources-{username}` folder:

```
   │   pom.xml
   └───src
       └───main
           ├───java
           │       ConfigurationLoader.java
           ├───external-resources-drvdijk
           │       conf.properties
           ├───resources
           │       conf.default.properties
           └───webapp
               │   web.xml
               └───WEB-INF
```

Then, in the `pom.xml`, we included:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>development</id>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/external-resources-${user.name}</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

This enables every team member to create his own `external-resources-{username}` directory, enabling the Maven profile, and building.

Our version of the `ConfigurationLoader.java` (actually called differently in our project) would first read all the properties from `conf.default.properties` file (they could also be "empty" properties, e.g. `db.username =`). Then, it would load the `conf.properties` included by the Maven profile or in the application server's `lib` directory, and overwrite all existing properties found in the `conf.default.properies` with the ones found in the `conf.properties`.

In our `conf.default.properties` we explicitly list all the properties our application can handle. If after loading all properties (including `conf.properties`) some are missing (or some unknown ones are found), the application would raise a lot of errors and refuse to start.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: +1 beat me to it. Profiles are the way to go. They can be declared within the POM or externally in a settings file and enabled on demand. For another example see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15120229/best-practice-for-defining-machine-specific-resources-in-maven-builds/15123042#15123042

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Please see my upd above for more descriptive comment.

Answer (score 1):

Though there are problably a variety of solutions I would prefer the following:

Use two different classes that implement the same interface (e.g. the `ConfigurationLoader` interface), one that would handle configuration from classpath and one that would handle the file case. Use a property file for your application (e.g. app.properties) that would be created by your build (different values for prod and dev) and would always reside in the same place in classpath e.g. the root package. Inside this file you would have the following properties:

```
config.loader.class=com.mycompany.ClasspathConfigurationLoader  # or FileConfigurationLoader for prod environment
config.loader.resource.classpath=resources/conf1.properties  # use classloader.getResourceAsStream() to load this resource
config.loader.resource.file=/path/to/tomcat/home/bin/conf1.properties
```

Now since your loader is a singleton you would have a static block that would read the property file and based on the first property it would decide what type of instance to create as a `ConfigurationLoader` class.
Each different type of instance can then use the additional properties to decide which resource to load.

Comment: Hi, thank you, that is my solution for now, but there are issues with referencing other resources from that property file. I think I will need to repeat loader for those resource in the manner of ConfigurationLoader's several implementations. See my update